# How to have multiple people connect to an Azure SQL database via Power BI Desktop?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

For a training I would like to have multiple students connect to an Azure SQL database via Power BI Desktop. These students are all over the world so there is no specific IP range or fixed set of IP addresses I can whitelist. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not much you can do. I would create a new database at the beginning of the course, create one user for the students, open all IPs and delete the database at the end of the training.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you create a single Power BI report using an admin account, and  then define Row Level Security in your dataset.

Refer - https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/connect-two-different-users-on-same-azure-database-on-the-same/td-p/513463